# How do I remove duplicate child div from different parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a little game on html and I have two issues (listed below).

My html is simple, the important parts are that I have two parent divs placed next to each other and they are shaped as aquariums (aq1 and aq2). Aq1 can have some fish initially. All fish are known and new can't be created.

The player can open the gates to aq2 to fill it with fish (< p> formed as fish with css) . The player can press the fish for it to disappear and show up in aq1. And vice versa. Thus, fun is inevitable.

Issue 1. There is one crab in the mix. I don't want more than one. How do I check if it already showed up in aq1 initially and prevent it from showing up again when aq2 is filled?

Issue 2. Is there a solution to this in css? It would be more elegant that way.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.tagsFish').live('click', function(e) {  

    $(this).hide();
    var tagFish = $(this).attr('id');
    tagFish='#'+tagFish+'1';

    $(tagFish).show();
});
$('.newFish').live('click', function(e) {  

    $(this).hide();
    var newFish = $(this).attr('id').replace('1', '');
    newFish='#'+newFish;

    $(fish).show();
});

$('.openGates').live('click', function(e) { 
  $('.openGates').toggleClass('closeGates').text('-'); 

    $('#fishChoices').show();
    var choices = $('#fishChoices');
    var newfish = "";

    newfish += '<p id="fish1" class="fish"> fish </p>'
    +'<p id="fish2" class="fish"> fish </p>'
    +'<p id="fish3" class="fish"> fish </p>'
    +'<p id="fish4" class="fish"> fish </p>'
    +'<p id="fish5" class="fish"> fish </p>'
    +'<p id="fish6" class="fish"> crab </p>'
    +'<p id="fish7" class="fish"> fish </p>'
    +'<p id="fish8" class="fish"> fish </p>'
    +'<p id="fish9" class="fish"> fish </p>'; 
    choices.html(newfish);
});
$('.closeGates').live('click', function(e) {
$('.closeGates').text('+'); 

    $('#fishChoices').hide();
    });
});
```

My attempt. I've

```
var classes = $('#'+aquarium).attr('class').split(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {

      $('#'+classes[i]+'1').hide();
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Also, please post all the relevant code (HTML and CSS) so that we can replicate your issue and show you a working answer.

Comment: The JQuery `live` method was deprecated many years ago. Use `.on()` instead. Also, can't you just set a Boolean "flag" to `true` when the crab gets created and check that flag before creating a second one?

Comment: Adding <p> tags like so is inefficient.  Instead, use the DOM built-in functions (createElement, createTextNode, .append(), etc. ) to create nodes and register a click event handler to each generated <p> node.   When a <p> tag is clicked, just append it to target -- this will automatically remove and reattach the <p> to destination without having to check if it's there or not.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: My idea was more that I scrape aq1 for all initial fish and crab and then compare them.

Comment: I think the better approach is to just keep track of what's been created at the moment of creation.

Comment: Agree with @ScottMarcus, don't use HTML as your application state. Maintain a true state of the game in JS objects/arrays to whatever degree you feel able right now. And then create HTML elements corresponding to those objects. Imagine this - that your game could be played without there being an HTML representation of it. It may seem like more effort but it will pay you back in the long run, and fun is inevitable ;)